# MobX: Observed Component does not rerender after observable change

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, mobx, mobx-react

I have a basic MobX setup in React Native, but my component does not rerender after an observable is getting updated and I can't seem to figure out why.

react-native *0.56.1*; react *16.4.1*; mobx *4.5.0*; mobx-react *5.2.8*

**Store**

```
class AppStore {
  drawer = false;
  toggleDrawer = () => {
    this.drawer = !this.drawer;
  }
}
decorate(AppStore, {
  drawer: observable,
  toggleDrawer: action
});

const app = new AppStore();
export default app;
```

**Component**

```
class _AppLayout extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      drawerAnimation: new Animated.Value(0)
    };
  }

  UNSAFE_componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    console.log('will not get called');
    if (this.props.app.drawer !== nextProps.app.drawer) {
      Animated.timing(this.state.drawerAnimation, {
        toValue: nextProps.app.drawer === true ? 1 : 0,
        duration: 500
      }).start();
    }
  }

  render() {
    console.log("will only be called on first render");
    const translateX = this.state.drawerAnimation.interpolate({
      inputRange: [0, 1],
      outputRange: [0, -(width - 50)]
    });

    return (
      <Animated.View style={[styles.app, { transform: [{ translateX }] }]}>
        <View style={styles.appContent}>
          <RouterSwitch />
        </View>
        <View style={styles.appDrawer} />
      </Animated.View>
    );
  }
}
const AppLayout = inject("app")(observer(_AppLayout));
```

**Trigger (from different component)**

```
<TouchableOpacity
  onPress={() => {
    app.toggleDrawer();
    // will reflect the new value
    console.log(app.drawer)
  }}
  style={styles.toggle}
/>
```

EDIT:
After some investigation no rerender was triggered because I didn't use the store in the `render()` method, only in `componentWillReceiveProps`. This seems super weird to me?

When I use the store in render, even by just assigning a variable, it starts working:

```
const x = this.props.app.drawer === false ? "false" : "true";
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As per mobx docs,

> The observer function / decorator can be used to turn ReactJS components into reactive components. It wraps the component's render function in mobx.autorun to make sure that any data that is used during the rendering of a component forces a re-rendering upon change. It is available through the separate mobx-react package.

So you need to use the `this.props.app.drawer` inside render function of observer component to receive reactions from mobx.

Refer [this link](https://github.com/mobxjs/mobx/blob/gh-pages/docs/best/react.md#mobx-only-tracks-data-accessed-for-observer-components-if-they-are-directly-accessed-by-render) for more details about how and when mobx reacts.

Answer (score 3):

You need to use `observer` from `mobx-react` on your component, also using decorators is the best practice. Also make sure you're using Provider on your Root component

**Store**

```
class AppStore {
  @observable drawer = false;
  @action toggleDrawer = () => {
    this.drawer = !this.drawer;
    console.log(this.drawer)
  }
}
```

**Component**

```
const app = new AppStore();
export default app;

@observer 
class AppLayout extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      drawerAnimation: new Animated.Value(0)
    };
  }

  UNSAFE_componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    console.log('will not get called');
    if (this.props.app.drawer !== nextProps.app.drawer) {
      Animated.timing(this.state.drawerAnimation, {
        toValue: nextProps.app.drawer === true ? 1 : 0,
        duration: 500
      }).start();
    }
  }

  render() {
    console.log("will only be called on first render");
    const translateX = this.state.drawerAnimation.interpolate({
      inputRange: [0, 1],
      outputRange: [0, -(width - 50)]
    });

    return (
      <Provider app={app}>
        <Animated.View style={[styles.app, { transform: [{ translateX }] }]}>
          <View style={styles.appContent}>
            <RouterSwitch />
          </View>
          <View style={styles.appDrawer} />
        </Animated.View>
      </Provider>
    );
  }
}
```

**Trigger**

```
<TouchableOpacity
  onPress={() => {
    app.toggleDrawer();
    // will reflect the new value
    console.log(app.drawer)
  }}
  style={styles.toggle}
/>
```

Comment: Why can‘t I use `decorate`? It‘s in the documentation. If you look at my code you see that I‘m using observer. Provider is also in my Root Component

Comment: Are you using Typescript or Babel?